# how to get previous day in PHP

Tags: php

I know how to get the current date in PHP like so---

```
echo date("Y/m/d")
```

But I am not sure how to get it the previous day. **I mean today is 2015-08-10**, so how I can get yesterday's date **2015-08-09**.

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Is it the solution, but do not know how it can solve my problem.

Does anyone know how to get the previous day in the PHP?

I have looked a lot but did not find any simple solution for this, anyone knows any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try google? https://www.google.com/?q=how+to+get+previous+day+in+PHP

Comment: Minus 5.. 4 answers and 0 close votes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use this-

```
date('Y/m/d',strtotime("-1 days"));
```

Or Use `DateTime` class like this-

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->modify("-1 days")->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('2015-08-10')))
```

And you will get the previous day of 2015-08-10, To get the previous date from current date simple use this.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"));
```

For more details follow the official [site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 11):

You can modify a PHP DateTime object, it's fairly simple to add or subtract date intervals, this is the first example in the manual.

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

[date modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Answer (score 1):

Get yesterday :

```
$hour = 12;    
$today              = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
$yesterday          = strtotime("-1 day", $today);
```